# Testing dynamic directive which uses $compile internally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test a directive which compiles internally using $compile provider based on options I pass

The problem with the suggested tests in the angular website is that they assume you specified a template in your directive, not that you dynamically create your element inside your directive.

This is my test :

```
describe('Directives', function() {
  var $compile,
    $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('vcm-spa'));
  beforeEach(module('Directives'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('Compiles the text inside a label', function() {
    var element = $compile('<bttn text="this is some text" class="basic big mrts" action="login()"> </bttn>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect(element.html()).toContain("this is some text");
  });
});
```

The problem is that of course element.html is empty because I did not specify a template.

How can I manually execute my link method which uses $compile?

My directive :

```
angular.module('Directives').directive('bttn', [ '$compile', 
  function( $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var t = '<div ng-click="$action" class="ui button $classes">\
                            <i class="{{$id.icon}} "></i>\
                            $text\
                     </div>';
        t = t.replace(/\$text/g, $attrs.text);

        $scope.t = t;
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        var t = scope.t;
        unescape(t);
        element.html(t);
        var e = $compile(t, {
          transclude: true
        })(scope);
        element.replaceWith(e);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: it seems to be [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/aVCwD7PFb5tWrWsY1qAH)

Comment: that is very strange, maybe because jasmine is executing in the web mode? anyways seems to be an issue with jasmine then, thanks